# VSCode: how to run yapf to format on save the file

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, formatting, yapf

I recently installed **yapf** using pip and configured the settings.json file of vscode but I don't know **how to run yapf formatting the current opened file on save**. Any clue?

here is my `settings.json` file:

```json
    "[python]": {
        "editor.defaultFormatter": "ms-python.python",
        "editor.tabSize": 4,
        "editor.insertSpaces": true,
        "editor.formatOnSave": true,
        "editor.formatOnSaveMode": "modifications",
        "editor.formatOnType": true,
        "editor.formatOnPaste": true,
    },
    "python.formatting.provider": "yapf",
    "python.formatting.yapfPath": "/usr/local/bin/yapf",
    "python.linting.lintOnSave": true,
    "python.linting.enabled": true,
    "python.defaultInterpreterPath": "python3",
```

Here is my `.style.yapf` file:

```yaml
[style]
based_on_style = google
spaces_before_comment = 4
indent_width: 2
split_before_logical_operator = true
column_limit = 180
```

I am using:

- Mac OS 11.6.1.
- VS Code 1.64.0